# Wordpress code plugin for android or similar app?

Tags: android, wordpress

## A little background:

I am looking for an Android app or a plugin for the wordpress app to format code in my new blog as I plan on writing a tutorial on how to use the Droidscript engine to write a mobile game.

## Edit:

I attempted using the `<code>` html tag, but it was buggy at best in the Wordpress app. I **did** do a search on the Google Play store, but as @Izzy said in the comments, 300 or so results is hard to sort through.

It was also brought to my attention that my question might not be complete enough to be considered answerable. I am looking for an app under 50 megabytes that can format code and has keyword highlighting (not sure if that is the correct term). Take the SE code formatting as an example of what I want. It has to support keywords in at least Javascript, but preferably should support Java, C#, Lua, and as many other languages as possible.

I have no access to a Desktop or laptop or home internet connection so it should work offline.

I am willing to pay up to $10 for the app I am looking for.

## Question

Anyone have a good alternative piece of software?

## List of requirements:

- Must have ability to display code in an easy-to-recognize manner.
- Must cost at or less than $10.
- Must run on less than 50 mb of RAM
- Ideally supporting key words in different colors
- Extra points if U can use it to totally replace the Wordpress app and do all of my blogging from it (e.g. Not a plugin, but an independent app).

Comment: @Izzy Did the edits improve it enough?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the "developer options" for a blogging tool – but apart from that, I'd say so. Another confusion might be on your end: Are you speaking of max 50 MB ***app size*** (quite a big thing then) – or ***RAM usage*** (as your second mentioning suggests)? The latter is hardly predictable, as it much depends on what you do with an app.

Comment: @Izzy I actually mean both. 50 mb of RAM and/or disk space can be used.

Comment: As I wrote: disk space for the app (not counting data) can be determined. RAM usage depends on too many different criteria, so that part cannot be guaranteed. Nevertheless, I must leave it to others answering the question (I'm not a WP guy).

Comment: @Izzy In my experience with android, apps have a general range of RAM to use (e.g. 40-50mb or 10-20 mb).

Comment: Then your experience differs from mine. Nevermind, let's leave that to those who know the apps – and might have experience concerning their RAM usage as well :)